# Postgresql trigger set empty string to NULL

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have a table with field "mac" of type MACADDR. Now I would like to treat a situation (probably with trigger?) when somebody inserts empty string instead of mac address. I would like to turn this empty string to NULL, so postgresql will not complain: *invalid input syntax for type macaddr: ""*

What I have now in trigger function is this:

```
IF CHAR_LENGTH(NEW.mac) = 0 THEN
  NEW.mac := NULL;
END IF;
```

But it does not seem to work. What would you do, if you want to treat this on DB level?

Thank you very much. -Jan

PS: I am a postgresql newbie. But a fascinated one :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do what you want with a trigger. Your incoming empty string will be parsed and converted to a `macaddr` (or at least the parsing will be attempted) **before** the trigger is executed. However, you could write a simple function to convert empty strings to NULL and use that in your INSERT:

```
create function macaddr_ify(m varchar) returns macaddr as $$
begin
    if m is null or length(m) = 0 then
        return null;
    end if;
    return cast(m as macaddr);
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

And then:

```
insert into t (addr) values (macaddr_ify(str));
```

I'd recommend that your client application properly convert empty MAC address strings to NULLs itself though.

Comment: Cool, thank you! That is a beautiful function. I am trying to put maximum logic to DB, as there will be a lot of applications and dumb scripts accessing it.

Comment: I've received one more possible solution to this. Can help sbd mabye... One good guy says to use a "fake" table with varchars and a trigger to put it into the final table. Well... that's dirty. I love it! :D

Comment: @Petr: A fake table to hold **all** possible MAC addresses? Or insert into a "fake" table and then do an `INSERT ... SELECT` thing?

Comment: The latter one: insert into a fake table and then trigger that will move it into the real one. Or one more way I got told yesterday: "mac_text" varchar field in the same table and a trigger that will convert/move it into "mac" macaddr field.

Comment: @Petr: Sounds like a lot of pointless busy-work to me. Sure, you could do all those things but you'd still have people inserting directly into the table with the real `macaddr` column. Fixing the client applications to behave themselves still seems like the best solution to me.